# How to make each page element non-printable by default in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, printing, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to specify explicitly elements that should get printed with

```
.visible-print-block
.visible-print-inline
.visible-print-inline-block
```

classes. I don't want to cover everything with `hidden-print`, is there a way to achieve that with a tiny css effort?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The `.hidden-print` class just adds `display: none!important` to the element within a `print` media query:

```
@media print {
    .hidden-print {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to hide *all* elements by default when printing, you could use the following:

```
@media print {
    * {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to exclude the `.visible-print-*` classes, you could use:

```
@media print {
    body *:not(.visible-print-block):not(.visible-print-inline):not(.visible-print-inline-block) {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: The lowest variant makes the page unprintable, browser says there's an error occurred while trying to render preview

Comment: It has to be also `*:not(html):not(body)`

Comment: @Lu4 Good point. Updated. It will still be problematic at times though. You might have a child element with class `.visible-print-block`, but if its immediate parent isn't the `body` element, it will still be hidden (because the parent is hidden). You would need to explicitly set the class `.visible-print-block` on the upper-most parent element, I guess.

Comment: That's what I'd like to get away from, as soon as I define `.visible-print-block` or similar I would like to be showing the parents and the children of the element that defines that class...